# Add Button to B2C SelfAsserted Technical Profile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm looking for an option to add a button to a SelfAsserted technical profile, which executes another technical profile (a REST API in my case) 
I already had a look into displayControls, which apparently at this time only supports a full verification process with some mandatory steps and fields. Is there any option to just have a single button added that can be assigned an action?

Comment: Can you give context to the overall goal? You can’t add a button via policy but you can use your own JavaScript and html elements.

Comment: sure, I have a custom REST API that can be called for sending SMS. I want to utilize this mechanism for Multifactor Authentication. Right now, I'm doing so using a set of technical profiles in a user journey, that looks as follows:  

- create a code and call the sendsms api via rest technical profile using the phone number stored in the user attributes  

- selfasserted technical profile to let the user enter and validate the code  

In this case, I only have a single button to confirm the code. But I would also like to give users an option to re-send the code.

Comment: I also already created a version using VerificationControl, But in a case where the user is not asked to provide additional information in the same orchestrationstep, presenting VerificationControl feels like demanding a lot more actions than necessary (sms are not sent automatically and after providing a code, the user has to press verify and then continue right after another)

Comment: The only way to achieve this is by putting your own button which makes its own api calls. The best we can achieve using the service is here: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-sms-displaycontrol

There is no way to have the user be able to resend the code if you place the displayControl in a validation technical profile. The only option is to place it on a  selfAsserted page, but then the user has to click send code. You could use javascript to automatically click "send code" here.

Comment: You can also use javascript to click "Continue" after the user enters 6char code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @JasSuri . As we want to have the REST API protected by authentication, adding our own button with JavaScript will not be a good option for us. However, Modifying the page with JavaScript as you mentioned above looks like a way to get a suitable result. We'll be having a look into that. I keep you updated. :)